# Update progress bar in for loop

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I do see a lot of articles with similar titles but it's really touching on my issue.

I'm trying to update my progress bar from  within a `forEach` loop, i'm sending the % to my redux state and my progress bar component takes it from there, it all works fine(in the console) but in practice my UI is not updating while the loop is running since the UI is blocked out.
Is there a way around it? Or am i missing something very obvious?

**Main component**

```
const CollectData = async (props) => {
    resp = await CollectData()
    //more stuff
}
```

Logging storeData here in the console will continuously update

**CollectData**

```
array.forEach((x, index) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'PERCENT', payload: percentvalue})
    //doing stuff
}
```

**ProggressBar**

```
import { ProgressBar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';


const Percentage = () => {
    const storeData = useSelector(state => state)

    return (<div><ProgressBar animated now={storeData.percentage} label={`${storeData.percentage}%`} />{storeData.percentage}</div>)
}

export default Percentage
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe because the store.Dispatch is being called inside a forEach loop, the internal state of the useSelector isn't getting updated until the forEach has terminated. I could be wrong though. add a useEffect to your component and add storeData.percentage as a dependency, console log the result and that will tell you if the state is updating properly.

Comment: I already checked using a useEffect in my main component and storeData is being updated. I think the the issue is that the UI is stuck in the for loop and I'm not sure why

Comment: Also for clarification I'm using store.Dispatch and not the hook since it's regular function and not a component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to unblocking the UI by implementing a setTimeout promise like so

```
const pause = () => {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0))
}
```

and calling it here which gives the UI enough time to update the progress
. I'm pausing the forEach loop few loops to updating the UI and continuing

```
array.forEach((x, index) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'PERCENT', payload: percentvalue})
    if (index % 20 === 0) { await pause() }
    //doing stuff
}
```